# Filtering the right path to implement dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: java, path

I have a goal and a starting point and a list of obstacles which are rectangles. My starting point is (0, 0) now I have perform dijkstra's algorithm to traverse from start to goal avoiding the obstacles. I can travel through the sides of the rectangle to reach the goal, but I cannot go through, basically all the points that form my rectangle are the vertices.

My input file is of this format
    1.75 -0.25
    -0.5   2.5  -1    1
    0.75  1.31 -0.56 0.25
    2     2.32  0.35 0.75

something like this ..
    (xgoal ygoal
    xmin0 xmax0 ymin0 ymax0
    xmin1 xmax1 ymin1 ymax1
    ...
    xminN xmaxN yminN ymaxN)

(line 1 is goal
line 2 is the boundary arena
line 3, line4, and thereafter... Are a list of obstacles, I.e rectangles)

Help: I have parsed the file and extracted all the points, the rectangles (obstacles)
           I have a list which stores all the edges from a given point to every other point and 
           and a EdgeList which has the list of all the edges.

Can anyone tell me how to filter out the edges (obstacles) and generate a right path to implement dijkstra's.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
//import DrawingRects;





import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GlobalNav {

//private static BufferedReader br;
    public static final ArrayList<Float> storeCoordinateList = new ArrayList<Float>();
    public static final ArrayList<Rectangle2D> rectangleList = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();
    public static final ArrayList<Float> storeCoordinates = new ArrayList<Float>();
    public static final ArrayList<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

//ArrayList<Float> storeCoordinateList = new ArrayList<Float>();  
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);  
// Get the object of DataInputStream  
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  
        String strLine;  
//Read File Line By Line  
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {  
            String[] nums = strLine.split(" ");
            for (String n : nums){
                try {
                    Float num = Float.parseFloat(n);
                    storeCoordinateList.add(num);
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e){

                }
            }    
        }


//Close the input stream 
        System.out.println("Co-ordinate List " + storeCoordinateList);
        in.close();  
        System.out.println("Size of Coo " + storeCoordinateList.size());

        System.out.println("GlobalNav.main()4 " + storeCoordinateList.size());
        int x1 = 2, x2 = 3, y1 = 4, y2 = 5;
//int xmin = 2, xmax = 3, ymin = 4, ymax =5;
        System.out.println("GlobalNav.main()" + storeCoordinateList.size());

        int expansion = 210;
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(0, 0));

        while(y2 < storeCoordinateList.size()){
//System.out.println("GlobalNav.main()" + x1);
            float height = (storeCoordinateList.get(y2)) - (storeCoordinateList.get(y1));
            float width = (storeCoordinateList.get(x2)) - (storeCoordinateList.get(x1));
//Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Math.round(storeCoordinateList.get(x1)), Math.round(storeCoordinateList.get(y1)), Math.round(height), Math.round(width));
            Rectangle2D.Float rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(storeCoordinateList.get(x1), storeCoordinateList.get(y1), height, width);
            rectangleList.add(rect);


            points.add(new Point2D.Float(storeCoordinateList.get(x1), storeCoordinateList.get(y1)));
            points.add(new Point2D.Float(storeCoordinateList.get(x1), storeCoordinateList.get(y2)));
            points.add(new Point2D.Float(storeCoordinateList.get(x2), storeCoordinateList.get(y1)));
            points.add(new Point2D.Float(storeCoordinateList.get(x2), storeCoordinateList.get(y2)));

            x1 += 4;
            x2 += 4;
            y1 += 4;
            y2 += 4;

        }
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(storeCoordinateList.get(0), storeCoordinateList.get(1)));
        System.out.println("List" + rectangleList.toString());

        System.out.println("List" + points.toString());


        filterIntersectionEdges(points);


    }

    private static void filterIntersectionEdges(ArrayList<Point2D> points2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Edge> edge = new ArrayList<Edge>();
//edge.add(Point(0, 0));
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Edge>> listOfEdges = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Edge>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < points2.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < points2.size(); j++) {
                edge.add(new Edge(points2.get(i),points2.get(j)));

                listOfEdges.add(edge);

//              System.out.println("Edges" + edge.toString());
//              System.out.println("List of Edges" + listOfEdges.toString());
            }

        }



        Edge line1 = new Edge();
        int i = 0;
        for (ArrayList<Edge> newEdge : listOfEdges) {
            line1 = newEdge.get(i);




            for (Iterator iterator = newEdge.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Edge line2 = (Edge) iterator.next();
//System.out.println(" lIne 2 " + line2);



            }
            i++;


        } 


    }

}


class Edge{

    private Point2D pointA;
    private Point2D pointB;

    public Edge(Point2D pointA, Point2D pointB){
        this.pointA = pointA;
        this.pointB = pointB;
    }

    public String size() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    public Edge() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Point2D getPoint1(){
        return this.pointA;
    }

    public Point2D getPoint2(){
        return this.pointB;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Point 1:" + pointA.toString() + " Point 2:" + pointB.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please specify, what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I want to find the right path avoiding the obstacles, but I am not understanding how to go about it.